# How to display a currency format in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, format

In the model class, I am trying to display a currency format for the "Price" field, however the code I am using is not producing the desired result, and I have no idea why it is not working. I do not want to hard code the $ on every page, that would be a hassle. Here is the code I have in the model.

```
 public partial class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Price Each")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Due Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Date Received")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString= "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateReceived { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("W/O# or Cost Center")]
    public int PurchaseID { get; set; }

    public virtual PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make the property type `decimal`

Comment: also make sure you use EditorFor.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong property type.

try:

```
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: I made the change in the model, now I get a Data Entity Core Matching exception. How can I update the database to fix this problem?

Comment: you have to update your database http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx

Comment: If its a currency, and you don't want to risk mathematical errors, it really should be `decimal`, not `double`

Comment: ups.. sorry my bad. (i corrected my answer)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when